# How to name the browser tab title magento2

Tags: magento2

How to set the browser tab title for a module.

UPDATE:

i tried as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Core/etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <mpage>
        <general>
            <enable_in_frontend>1</enable_in_frontend>
            <head_title>My Title</head_title>
        </general>
    </mpage>
</default>
</config>
```

But still i get the url itself shows in my broswer tab..not the title i defined..

Comment: check browser spelling before post. i cant edit if i can, i will edit. if you find its useful, upvote on my comment

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue and the suggested solutions here don't work

Answer (score 2):

In `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout` in xml files you have to write :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
          <title>Your Tab Title</title>
       </head>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="root">
        <action method="setHeaderTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Page Title</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This comes even in the page...i want only in the browser tab

Comment: Pl check my updated answer

Comment: I have updated as per ur answer @Ashish, i get the same title in both the places

Comment: If you not set the Header title then Head title will be display at both places. Its a default property of browser. You have to set both title then it will display properly.

Comment: I dont wnt the page title @Ashish, i want only tab title, so removed page title value...then what to set in header title

Comment: Try with space char or "&nbsp;"

Comment: I tried this solution but didn't work. The head title is not changing.

Comment: @AshishJagnani This solution also not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

[YOUR_NAMESPACE]/[YOUR_MODULE]/etc/config.xml

(update tag yourmodulename, replace it with your actual module name all in small letters )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <yourmodulename>
             <general>
                <page_title>Your Page Title</page_title>
            </general>
        </yourmodulename>
    </default>
</config>
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Hey @Ekta..please find the updated answer...i took the help of ur code and updated the code, but still the url itself appears in the tab...why?

Comment: @SachinS please replace head_title with page_title

Comment: Initially I tried that only... It dint work. So I tried with head_title.. It's not working in both cases after clearing cache

Comment: Can you share your code for module somewhere? Becuase this works perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My title</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Please try this, It will works..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use :
your_object_of_pageFactory ->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__(you_page_title));

add this to you Controller of page.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Content >> Pages.

Go to your homepage and rename it.

Then go to Content >> Pages >> [your home page] >> Search Engine Optimization...

And change the details on meta description etc.

Then flush your cache in System >> Cache Management.

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Any of these answers worked for me (using Magento 2.1). The title wasn't correctly translated and was just printed in raw English.

However, I've found this solution on another website and it worked fine.

Just add this piece of code in the page Block class you want to translate :

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Inventory'));
}
```

The i18n translation file has to be set. Here is an example for the French file "i18n/fr_FR.csv" :

```
"Inventory","Inventaire"
```

My source : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5231#issuecomment-385248982